# How to establish telnet connection between two macs via Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, telnet

I have Macpro (late 2013, Yosemite 10.10.4) and Macbookpro (mid 2010, Yosemite 10.10.4) connected to home network via Wi-Fi (using router Actiontech T1200H)

I'm able to ssh both ways without any problems (). But when I try telneting:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.64
Trying 192.168.1.64...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.64: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Any ideas hot to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet is disabled by default in OS X because it is fundamentally insecure, and it should never be enabled on a machine directly connected to the internet.

Assuming you have a good reason for using telnet rather than SSH, and understand the security risks, you can start the telnet server using:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/telnet.plist
```

And stop it again using

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/telnet.plist
```

Note the above commands are permanent and will survive across a reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just for security testing and demonstration purposes!